# Beginner C: error: control reaches end of non-void function?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a greedy algorithm and I get this error:

```
greedy2.c:27:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function
      [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 error generated.
```

with this code:

```
int man(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  float amount;
  do
    {
      printf("Input dollar amount owed:\n");
      amount = GetFloat();
    }
  while (amount <= 0);    
  int coins = 0;
  while (amount >= 0.25);
  {
    amount = amount - 0.25;
    coins++;
  }
  printf("Number of coins to use: %d\n", coins);

}
```

What is wrong with my curly braces, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb here and guess that your compiler doesn't like `int man`. Use `int main` instead.

Comment: It could be the fact that you mispelled `main`.

Comment: @AdrianJandl Technically, the compiler will be perfectly happy with `int man` (when it actually returns an `int` of course). The linker, however, is going to be less happy when there is no `main`.

Comment: There are 10 **Related** questions with the exact same error message. Are you trying to tell us that none of them answered your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question briefly, add:

```
return 0;
```

before the end of `main()`.

You also have a typo in the name. It's probably `main`, not `man`.

To give you a longer answer, you defined `main` as returning an integer (`int`) but have no `return` statement at the end of it, so it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing wrong with your curly brackets. Problem is that you declared your main as returning int.. but you are not returning anything

If you compile with the compiler flag `-Wall` .. your compiler will complain when you don't return something from a function that you have defined as returning something..

just add:

```
  return 0; // before the last bracket
```

Also its  `int main(int argc, char* argv[]){` .. not `int man(int argc, char* argv[]){`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are doing this in `main()` function. There is typo in your function name. Return type of `main()` is `int` so you should something from the function. say `return 0; //Success` at the end of `main()` function.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is your simple typo, it's `main()` not `man()`.

Although it's the correct way to also `return 0` at the end of a main function, you asked why your code wasn't working and that's not the reason. Even though i I shouldn't I run C programs all the time and I seldom ever `return 0`. Also, make sure your custom function `GetFloat` is in the same directory as your current code otherwise it'll come up with an error, and make sure that works too.

You can still do int man() if that was your intention, but you still need the int main function and you would have to call your man function like this:

```
int main()
{
man();
return 0; //This isn't crucial, code will still run
}
```