# control reaches end of non-void function with custom exit function

Tags: c, gcc, return, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

While trying to rid my code of GCC warnings I have discovered a strange bug/behaviour. My program uses a custom exit function which performs some clean-up and finally calls `exit()`.

However my use of this exit function is causing GCC to produce spurious warnings of:

> control reaches end of non-void function with custom exit function

An example of a program causing this bug is:

File1.c:

```
extern void CleanExit(int ExitCode);

int MyFunc(int ErrorCode)
{
    if(-1 == ErrorCode)
        return -1;
    if(1 == ErrorCode)
        return 1;
    if(2 == ErrorCode)
        return 0;
    if(3 == ErrorCode)
        CleanExit(0);
    CleanExit(-1);
}
```

File2.c:

```
void CleanExit(int ExitCode)
{
    /* Do Some Cleanup */
    exit(ExitCode);
}
```

Is there some way to be rid of these warnings without adding useless cruft to every function which uses this structure?

I would prefer to do so with standard C but am willing to use some kind of GCC pragma if needed.

Comment: Did you mean `exit(ExitCode)` instead of `exit(int ExitCode)`? And just move the `exit()` from `CleanExit()` function to `MyFunc()` function to get rid of the warning.

Comment: Function MyFunc do not have a return. 
This already discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669851/beginner-c-error-control-reaches-end-of-non-void-function

Comment: @CoolGuy You are correct with the correction, sorry. I messed up while creating a minimal example. Though With regards to moving the exit out, I will do that as a last resort, but am hoping if possible to find a way which does not force me to modify every call to CleanExit, as there are hundreds across many files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You tagged your question with GCC. So instead of changing function from `void` to `int` and adding `return` everywhere, you can try and GCC specify attribute. Add `__attribute__((noreturn))` above `CleanExit()` declaration. This will alert the compiler that `CleanExit()` will never return directly to the caller.

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed add a compiler specific line, but given gcc is the only compiler which causes the warning I should be able to easily enough ifdef this and get the right behaviour. Thanks

Comment: If you have a C11 compiler, no need to use an extension. Now there is the keyword `_Noreturn` that you can use instead.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
extern int CleanExit(int ExitCode);

int MyFunc(int ErrorCode)
{
    if(-1 == ErrorCode)
        return -1;
    if(1 == ErrorCode)
        return 1;
    if(2 == ErrorCode)
        return 0;
    if(3 == ErrorCode)
        return CleanExit(0);
    return CleanExit(-1);
}

int CleanExit(int ExitCode)
{
    /* Do Some Cleanup */
    exit(ExitCode);
}
```

Comment: but don't you need to return a value in `CleanExit`?

Comment: Since you are calling `exit` inside that function there will be no warning.

Comment: Downvote without a comment is rude, I would love to know what is wrong with this approach so I learn from you.

Answer (score -1):

Those warnings aren't spurious - there **is** a difference between returning from a function (and eventually exiting by returning from `main`) and calling `exit()` within another function to terminate the entire program. You don't really need to know those differences in this instance, but you can [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461449/return-statement-vs-exit-in-main) about [them](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gnu.gcc.help/bjSRy0eAcpU/WtHPMADFSIMJ) if you'd like.

In this case, the problem is with your function's signature. `MyFunc` is expected to return an `int`, but doesn't when `CleanExit` is called. As a result, the compiler complains about a missing return (but is smart enough to recognize an `exit` call and note it in the place of a return).

To solve the problem, simply add a dangling return after `CleanExit`. Because `CleanExit` will terminate the entire program, you won't have to worry about the significance of that value:

```
...
CleanExit(-1);
return -1;
...
```

Comment: On some compilers this will produce a warning about unreachable code